# VNC and Retropie- is it even possible?

Tags: vnc, retropie

I'm a newbie working with Raspbian or its RetroPie version, so my question might be quite simple to answer: The point is to make RetroPie show emulation(playing game) on another computer using some kind of VNC. As I understand, the RetroPie doesn't even have graphical shell, so x11vnc cannot help me. Are there any other possibilities to achieve video translation?

Similar questions were simply abandoned, so I had to ask myself

Sorry for my poor English - learning German right now

P.s. I would also like to variate aspect ratio of that screen.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better off adding a hdmi capture card to the PC, and connecting the Pi HDMI port to that.

The problem with streaming is you need to transmit:
screen resolution x3 (rgb) color x 30fps.
800x600x3x30 = 41mb/s.
If you need a larger resolution or higher frame rate you quickly exceed what networking can handle.

Recording in H.264 or H.265 and streaming that will probably be too much for your device when you consider it still has to render the game.

Comment: This doesn't answer whether it is possible to use VNC with RetroPie.  I'd like to know the answer to this, as I want to be able to configure within RetroPie before connecting to my final display, regardless of latency.

Comment: This answer: https://retropie.org.uk/forum/topic/19747/vnc-on-retropie/3 suggests that it is not possible